# string replace multiple words in one sentence

Tags: php, str-replace

I am making a tagging system in which there are user ids separated by comma in database . I call them after words and then break them and get the real user names for those ids . I am using `str_replace` to replace those words from a status update with their profile links (like facebook tag a friend) . The problem is how to replace multiple tags within the sentence ?

```
function tags($final_message,$tag_id)
{
    GLOBAL $con;
    if ($tag_id!==0)
    {
        $tag_id_explode=explode(",",$tag_id);
            foreach($tag_id_explode as $id)
        {   
        $tag_friend_query=mysqli_query($con,"select f_name,l_name from users_profile where user_id='$id'");
        $tag_friend_query_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tag_friend_query);
        $fname=$tag_friend_query_result['f_name'];
        $lname=$tag_friend_query_result['l_name'];
        $final_name=$fname.' '.$lname;
        $html="<a href='profile.php?id=".$id."'>".$final_name."</a>";

        }
            echo str_replace($final_name,$html,$final_message);

    }
}
```

This only converts one user and if there are multiple it does not work . If i put `str_replace` inside the loop then it works but it converts at a time and returns two different output with same sentence and one user being converted in each . It should be multiple users converted in just once sentence .

Comment: @zzlalani i am using mysqli .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
foreach($tag_id_explode as $id)
{   
    $tag_friend_query=mysqli_query($con,"select f_name,l_name from users_profile where user_id='$id'");
    $tag_friend_query_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($tag_friend_query);
    $fname=$tag_friend_query_result['f_name'];
    $lname=$tag_friend_query_result['l_name'];
    $final_name=$fname.' '.$lname;
    $html="<a href='profile.php?id=".$id."'>".$final_name."</a>";
    $final_message = str_replace($final_name,$html,$final_message);
}
echo $final_message;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems here when you use $final_name in str_replace(), it only has one last user's final name. Instead put it in the loop and in $html you are collecting the link, so you may want to do it in this way:
`$html .=yourlink;`

Please try the string concatinator dot after the variable (.)

Comment: i tried this before too and again since you suggested . but its not working it gives error undefined variable $html and then put the words to be replaced in the end of the sentence instead of replacing them where they are

Comment: define the variable before the loop starts
$html = '';